# How to grant a specific list of users access to Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

Currently when I click on the "Send Form" button in Google Forms users will be able to input the form when they know the URL.

Is it possible to grant a specific user to have access to the form?

(So I can revoke some user later without changing the URL?)

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is no way to limit a user to send a response, but you could allow only one response per user. See [View and manage users responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)